# How to open and write to a second Transcript in Pharo?

Tags: pharo

I want to open a second transcript and to write to it. Turns out that it does not work the way I would expect it to:

```
| second | 
second := ThreadSafeTranscript new.
second openLabel: 'A Second Transcript'.
second show: 'test'.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is missing is #stepGlobal, which is sent to the Transcript when the World steps.

Comment: Whoa. Thanks Leandro! So one must call #stepGlobal after every #show: in order for the window contents to be updated.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not sure how to proceed in this case (I'm not a Pharo user) so take my comment as a hint aimed at encouraging you to understand all of this better.

Comment: why do you need transcript?

Comment: Hmm. Why do you want to know @Uko ? :))

Comment: @mircealungu So that he can suggest a way of fixing your issue possibly in another way, See the [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Uko - I want to log messages to a Transcript-like window in a Transcript-like way, but I don't want the main Transcript itself. Does it make sense?

Comment: @mircealungu Makes a lot of sense. See my answer. I also was frustrated by this. Thanks for the kick in the assets.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is going to be complicated as there is logic buried deep inside the system so that multiple transcript windows are using the same ThreadSafeTranscript.

So, your best bet is to make your own and reuse the streaming API.

I've done one.

You can load it from http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/~philippeback/HOTranscript

[image: Transcripts all over the place]

You may want to put some critical: around some methods but well, if you use several HOTranscripts I guess it is best for you to deal with that. My take is that one does not need the critical: bit for such transcripts.